# $X_n \to X$ a.s. implies...

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $X_n$ be independent.
>
> $ X_n \to X \, a.s.$ implies $ \sum_n P( |X_n-X|>\epsilon) < \infty$

I tried to prove as follows, which is wrong.

Note that $ X_n \to X \, a.s.$ is equivalent to $\forall \epsilon>0, \, P( |X_n-X|>\epsilon \quad \textrm{i.o})=0.$

Then, using contraposition of 2nd Borel-Cantelli lemma, I get to the conclusion.

Here, I made a mistake on application of BC lemma since independence of $\{X_n\}$ does not imply independence of $\{X_n-X\}$.

Anyone who could give me some hint about this?

Thanks in advance.

---

Answer (score 10, accepted):

But actually $X_{n} - X$ are also independent. This is because $X$ is a.s. constant by a simple application of Kolmogorov's 0-1 Law, but this is sort of overkill. So let us give a more direct proof. We first refer to the following lemma:

> **Lemma.** $X_{1}, \cdots, X_{n}$ are independent if and only if
>   $$ \Bbb{E}[ f_{1}(X_{1})\cdots f_{n}(X_{n}) ] = \Bbb{E} f_{1}(X_{1}) \cdots \Bbb{E} f_{n}(X_{n})$$
>   for any bounded continuous functions $f_{1}, \cdots, f_{n}$.

Now let $f, g : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ be any bounded continuous functions. Then for any $m < n \ll k < l$, both $X_{m} - X_{k}$ and $X_{n} - X_{l}$ are independent. So

$$ \Bbb{E}[ f(X_{m} - X_{k}) g(X_{n} - X_{l})] = \Bbb{E} f(X_{m} - X_{k}) \Bbb{E} g(X_{n} - X_{l}). $$

Taking $l \to \infty$ followed by $k \to \infty$, the bounded convergence theorem says that

$$ \Bbb{E}[ f(X_{m} - X) g(X_{n} - X)] = \Bbb{E} f(X_{m} - X) \Bbb{E} g(X_{n} - X). $$

This implies that they are independent. (And this idea readily generalizes to show the mutual independence, not just the pairwise independence.)

> *Proof of Lemma.* The *'only if'* part is easy since $\sigma(X_{1}), \cdots, \sigma(X_{n})$ are independent. To prove the *'if'* part, for any $a_{1}, \cdots, a_{n}$, let
>
> $$ f_{i,k}(x)
> = \int_{x}^{\infty} k 1_{[a_{i},a_{i}+1/k]}(t) \, dt
> = \begin{cases}
> 1, \quad x \leq a_{i}, \\
> 0, \quad x \geq a_{i} + 1/k, \\
> \text{linearly interpolated in-between}
> \end{cases} $$
>
> Then we easily check that $f_{i,k} \downarrow 1_{(-\infty, a_{i}]}$. So by the bounded convergence theorem,
>   \begin{align*}
>  \Bbb{P}(X_{1} \leq a_{1}, \cdots, X_{n} \leq a_{n})
> &= \lim_{k\to\infty} \Bbb{E}[ f_{1,k}(X_{1}) \cdots, f_{n,k}(X_{n}) ] \\
> &= \lim_{k\to\infty} \Bbb{E} f_{1,k}(X_{1}) \cdots \Bbb{E} f_{n,k}(X_{n}) \\
> &= \Bbb{P}(X_{1} \leq a_{1}), \cdots,  \Bbb{P}(X_{n} \leq a_{n}).
> \end{align*}
>   This implies the independence of $X_{i}$'s (c.f. Theorem 2.1.4 in Durrett).

Comment: +1 for mentioning the overkill argument, then providing an elementary approach.

Comment: @Did, Thank you for upvote!

Comment: Wow, thx so much about your explanation.